# Am I constraining the CPU the correct way?

Tags: docker, cpu, scheduling

I'll admit it, I'm no expert at CPUs. And I might be doing it wrong all the way.

#### Testing environment

1. A CPU. According to [official specs](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/191075/intel-core-i5-9300h-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-10-ghz.html), it has **4 cores**, and **8 threads**.
2. Go. Fairly latest version, but it does not matter.
3. [gopsutil](https://github.com/shirou/gopsutil), a port of [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) originally written in Python.
4. Go Docker SDK

Using gopsutil, `cpu.Info()` reports that I have **8 physical threads**. The MHz value of each thread is 4100.

```golang
func main() {
    cpus, _ := cpu.Info()

    // number of cores
    fmt.Println(len(cpus))

    // MHz per CPU
    fmt.Println(cpus[0].Mhz)
}
```

#### Questions

1. Does this mean I have 4100 * 8 MHz of power? Or only 4100 MHz?
2. If I want a container to use 500MHz, do I use the value 500? Or 500 * 8?
3. How many vCPU do I have?

Here is how I'm constraining the value right now, I'm assuming I have total power of 4100 * 8 MHz.

```golang
func main() {
    cpuConstraintInMHz := 500
    cpuQuota := cpuConstraintInMHz * 1000 // in kHz
    cpuPeriod := 100000                   // in kHz

    hostConfig := &container.HostConfig{
        Resources: container.Resources{
            CPUQuota:  int64(cpuQuota),
            CPUPeriod: int64(cpuPeriod),
        },
    }

    _ = hostConfig
}
```

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense as you've written it.  There's a component inside the computer that emits an electrical signal 4100 million times per second; you don't usually say "I have 8 cores so I have 32 GHz now" or "I want this process to use only 500 MHz".  How much work actually gets done each clock cycle is very processor-dependent.

Comment: I suspect your actual answer is going to come down to a combination of the Linux kernel and Go runtime schedulers, and whether your process is actually CPU-bound (are you waiting on a database in another container?).  In Go, goroutines aren't bound to specific CPUs or OS threads, and counting processors may not be helpful.  The 99% answer is probably "delete the code in the question and don't worry about CPU allocation at all"; what is your actual goal here?

Comment: If I pass `--cpuset-cpus` to Docker, should I pass 1-4 (my total physical cores) or 1-8 (my total thread count), assuming that I want to use all the cpus?

Comment: I wouldn't pass that option at all.  By default the kernel will schedule your process on any and all of the CPUs, sharing with other processes as needed.

Comment: What we intend to do is, to ask users how much CPU power they have, how much they want to onboard, and then run a job/container constraining the limit at the onboarded value. Would this not work? I at least know that Docker can constraint the resources.

Comment: Resource constraints are generally better than CPU pinning.  The advice I've generally seen for [tag:kubernetes], though, is that you should generally declare how much minimum processor power you need (measured abstractly in "cores") but not set a maximum (set "requests" but not "limits"): using "more" CPU isn't harmful since the kernel scheduler can share cores between processes.